# Creating polygon of difference using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, vector

I have two polygon layers, each describing the Geomorphic units (GU) within a river channel across two surveys.

Using ArcMap (10.7.1), I would like to create a new layer, illustrating the change in the number and area of the different geomorphic units between the two surveys. I have attributes describing area, GU's etc. The number, classification and shape of the polygons differ between surveys, they do not share FID's.

[image]

I would like to create a .csv or (ideally) a shapefile showing

[image]

which GU's changed and what they changed from and into (i.e. pool to riffle).
Union tool does not produce the outcome I want; it creates a new shapefile of both surveys merged together.

Comment: Please choose one software stack to be the focus of your Question. Questions which ask about "ArcGIS or QGIS" are likely to be closed for asking two questions in one Question.

Comment: Are you saying that between the two surveys the shapes (polygons) don't change but their classification does eg. Rapid to Riffle? That sounds highly unlikely? You would normally use the Union tool to answer this type of change question so we don't know what you mean by "to no avail..."?

Comment: The channel adjusts between the two surveys, hence the shape, number and classification of each polygon will change. The only similarity between the two surveys is the overall shape of the channel. The union merges the two surveys but does not show me the difference between the two surveys. I want see how these two surveys differ.

Comment: Have you actually opened the attribute table of union result? You will get a polygon with the attributes of both layers, hence you can see the change. Edit your question and shows us the attribute table of the Union result and shows why you think the Union is not creating the results you seek.

Comment: thank you for your insightful comment. I was able to confirm the results were not what i wanted, from viewing the attribute table.  I have since found a workaround using the Riverscapes' GCD.